# Задваиваются строки при выборе SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне необходимо выбрать все столбцы из таблицы sales в которой есть столбец brand, и необходимо к ним добавить столбец brand из таблицы nomenclature_list, я делаю это с помощью такого запроса, но у меня задваиваются данные. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?:

```
SELECT sales.*, nomenclature_list.brand AS nBrand 
FROM sales
INNER JOIN nomenclature_list ON nomenclature_list.nmID = sales.nmId
WHERE sales.nmId = nomenclature_list.nmId AND sales.date BETWEEN '2023-08-11' AND '2023-09-11T23:59:59' AND sales.usr_id = '2' 
ORDER BY sales.date DESC
```

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Если добавить DISTINCT , то задвоенные данные пропадают и остаются уникальные. Вопрос, насколько корректно так делать в данном случае?

Comment: Раз задваиваются, значит у вас в nomenclature_list более 1 записи с nmId. А корректно ли делать distinct это уже вам самим решать, на основании того, что же лежит в этой таблице и могут ли быть разные brand к одному nmID. И если вдруг могут быть разные, то надо решить какой же из них вам нужен на выходе

Comment: Все зависит от поставленной задачи, которую вы пытаетесь решить. Однако, я бы посмотрел в строну качества данных в таблицах. Если nomenclature_list это некий список "товаров", то там есть записи с одинаковым nmId(чего быть не должно) - отсюда и задвоение

Comment: вы из выборки своецй возьмие задвоенную строку,  и возьмите ее `nmId`. Потом сделайте выборку из номеклатуры по этому ID. У вас получится столько строк, сколько дублей было. Затем решите, это корректно, что их там N штук, или нет. Если не должно быть - удалите и сделайте ограничение уникальности (PK,UIX). Если могут быть, то тут либо надо более корректно формулировать условие джойна, либо дистинкт.